# How to add focus listening using jquery to every input box?

Tags: jquery

Here is my attempt to add a listener which clears the placeholder on focus for every input box. Are there any errors evident in my code?

```
var $inputs = $('.add-item-form :input');
$inputs.each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.focus(function() {
        that.attr('placeholder') = '';
    })
});​
```

Comment: I indented your code, and gave an answer, now it's the tip turn, check every buggy  code you have with jsLint(You can use it at http://jsFiddle.net), it will notify of syntax errors you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.add-item-form :input').focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
that.attr('placeholder','');
```

insted of

```
that.attr('placeholder')='';
```

full code

```
 var $inputs = $('.add-item-form :input');
        $inputs.each(function() {
            var that = $(this);
            that.focus(function() {
                that.attr('placeholder','');
            })  
        });
```

as **gdoron** said, no need to cache dom objects, you can use **gdoron's** code much cleaner code

Comment: just provided evidence of errors which is asked by Hard worker

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-item-form :input').each(function() {
     var that = $(this);
     that.on('focus', function() {
         that.attr('placeholder','');
     });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-item-form:input').focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
});​
```

as gdoron suggested in addition you have to delete the extra space on jquery selector 
this: `'.add-item-form:input'`
instead of: `'.add-item-form :input'`

Comment: The code is copied and the selector might be wrong, there is a use of space in jQuery selectors!

Comment: Yes, of course there is a use of space in jQuery selectors, but in this case it is wrong for it to exist.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yVpA3/2/

Yes, Crystal Ball! :) Btw, thank you very much for your polite way of talking! :)

Comment: What about this [crystal ball](http://jsfiddle.net/yVpA3/3/)??? I'm sorry for being rude! but it's still just wrong...

Comment: @gdoron: Your answer isn't any better. All it is is a code block. Do you want the reader to do a diff or something to see if anything changed between the question and your answer? I'm not inclined to believe that he simply copied your answer, especially when he even said "as gdoron suggested".

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn. Then you can keep the "crystal ball" answer. It's my opinion.